# Скрыть значок на панели задач

Tags: windows, kotlin, compose-desktop

Как скрыть значок на панели задач в `kotlin compose desktop windows`.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос в том, как скрыть окно из панели задач, когда оно открыто, или - как спрятать окно в трей, а не закрывать?

Если второе, то — https://github.com/avdim/compose-desktop-not-shown-in-task-bar

(или [так с помощью Composable API](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/blob/master/tutorials/Window_API_new/README.md#hide-the-window-into-the-tray)).

Если первое, то нужно использовать собственный API: получать `ComposeWindow.windowHandle` и писать логику, специфичную для платформы, через **JNI**. Я не знаю точно, какой API для этого нужен, но это возможно. Возникнет еще одна проблема — скрыть окно с панели задач мы сможем только в том случае, если оно уже видно. Так вот будет небольшой глюк - на панели задач появляется окно на 300мс.

Comment: Хотел просто убрать значок с панели задач при открытом окне.

Comment: Можно небольшой пример